# drawing a dotplot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

This is my dataset below

```
dput(test21)
structure(list(Freq = c(9L, 7L, 7L, 4L), MonthAbb = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr")), .Names = c("Freq", "MonthAbb"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I know how to create a barplot using this data , however, I am interested in creating a dot plot like this below

[image]

One way to do this is as follows

```
a1 = seq(1, 9, length.out = 9)
a2 = rep(LETTERS[1], 9)
a = cbind(a1,a2)

b1 = seq(1, 7, length.out = 7)
b2 = rep(LETTERS[2], 7)
b = cbind(b1,b2)

c1 = seq(1, 7, length.out = 7)
c2 = rep(LETTERS[3], 7)
c= cbind(c1,c2)

d1 = seq(1, 4, length.out = 4)
d2 = rep(LETTERS[4], 4)
d= cbind(d1,d2)

test21a = as.data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d))
test21a$a1 = as.numeric(test21a$a1)

ggplot(data = test21a, aes(x=a2, y=a1, color = a2)) + geom_point()
```

But this is very inefficient, I am creating a sequence of numbers manually. Interested to find out if there is a better more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Does it have to be like that or will something like `dotchart(test21$Freq, labels = test21$MonthAbb, pch = 20, col = c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'grey'))` do ?

Comment: @steveb, i can do what you mentioned using `ggplot(data = test21, aes(x=MonthAbb, y=Freq)) + geom_point()` but that is not what I have in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can restructure you data to create a "barplot" equivalent with stacked dots.

```
# Restructure data
dat = data.frame(MonthAbb = rep(test21$MonthAbb, test21$Freq),
                 Count = sequence(test21$Freq))
dat$MonthAbb = factor(dat$MonthAbb, levels=month.abb)

ggplot(dat, aes(MonthAbb, Count - 0.5, fill=MonthAbb)) +
  geom_point(size=6, pch=21, show.legend=FALSE) +
  #geom_text(data=test21, aes(label=Freq, y=Freq), vjust=-0.5) + # To put labels above markers
  geom_text(data=test21, aes(label=Freq, y=Freq - 0.5)) + # To put labels inside topmost markers
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(dat$Count)), breaks=0:max(dat$Count)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="Month", y="Frequency")
```

[image]

However, it seems to me a line plot works better here:

```
test21$MonthAbb = factor(test21$MonthAbb, levels=month.abb)

ggplot(test21, aes(MonthAbb, Freq)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(test21$Freq)), breaks=0:max(test21$Freq)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="Month", y="Frequency")
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with line plot but the word frequency on the y axis is kind of misleading. I should have changed that to something more meaningful. But your solution is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks eipi10

Comment: I think you can simplify the expression defining `Count` to just `sequence(test21$Freq)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @alistaire. I have updated my answer. I remember learning about the existence of `sequence` somewhere in the foggy past, but haven't used it before.

Comment: @eipi10,  alistaire a cosmetic question, how do i add the label on top of each dotted line , 9, 7,7, 4 (max value).....?

Comment: You can do this with `geom_text`. See updated answer.